# What are the different editions of eXo Platform and where can I download the completely free edition?

Tags: content-management-system

I am trying to migrate my application to eXo Platform. However they have made it difficult to find the completely free edition. Can someone please attach a link to the completely free edition of eXo platform?

Answer (score 2):

You have the community edition of PLF 3.5 available from here http://forge.ow2.org/project/showfiles.php?group_id=151